Reading QuantumClifford.jl MixedDestabilizer state from a .csv file
This is more of a coding question, related to the Julia package QuantumClifford.jl. Hopefully this is the right place to ask.
I am trying to prepare a specific stabilizer state, and in order to not run that preparation code multiple times, I am storing the state in a .csv (or a .txt) file. Storing the state in a file is possible, but I cannot figure out how to read the state from the file into a state. The issue boils down to having a string str = "XII\nIXI" (that necessarily specifies a mixed state = fewer stabilizers than the number of qubits) and turning it into a state MixedDestabilizer(S"XII\nIXI"). Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Since I'm a quantum computing and Julia newbie, less technical answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Edit: other things I've tried:
Doing something like
using QuantumClifford:_T_str
var = "+ZII -IXI"
t = _T_str(var)
MixedDestabilizer(t)

raises an error, although  MixedDestabilizer(_T_str("+ZII -IXI")) works.
var = "+ZII -IXI" # This is the sort of format for something I've read in from a file
QuantumClifford.@S_str(var)

This raises an error saying var doesn't exist, but it works perfectly fine if I do QuantumClifford.@S_str("+ZII -IXI").

I figured it out, and I wrote functions for reading/writing Clifford states:
Writing:
using QuantumClifford
using CSV
using DataFrames
using Tables

function write_state(filename0::String, state0::MixedDestabilizer)
    s0 = split(replace(replace(string(state0), " " => ""), "_" => "I"), "━")[2]
    s1 = split(s0, "")[1]
    # println(s1) 
    stablst = split(s1, "\n")[2:end-1]
    # print(stablst)
    open(filename0, "a") do io
        write(io, "Time\n")
        for i in stablst
            write(io, string(i)*"\n")
        end
    end
end

function write_state_iter(filename0::String, 
    statelst0::Vector{MixedDestabilizer{QuantumClifford.Tableau{Vector{UInt8}, 
    Matrix{UInt64}}}})
    """
    Write a list of states = a single circuit iteration to a file
    """
    open(filename0, "a") do io
        write(io, "Iter\n")
    end
    for i in statelst0
        write_state(filename0, i)
    end
end

Reading:
function read_state(filename0::String)
    """
    This function returns the list of states stored in filename0.
    
    Format of filename0 contents: "Iter" separates different iterations, "Time"
    separates different timesteps. 
    """
    file0 = open(filename0, "r")
    circ_runs = read(file0, String)
    stab_iter_lst = split(circ_runs, "Iter")[2:end]
    iters = []
    for iter in stab_iter_lst
        stabstr = split(iter, "Time")[2:end] # remove "" at the beginning
        statestrlst = []
        for j in stabstr
            push!(statestrlst, string(strip(j, '\n')))
        end
        states = []
        for j in statestrlst
            st = @eval QuantumClifford.@S_str($j)
            push!(states, MixedDestabilizer(st))
        end
        push!(iters, states)
    end
    return iters
end

Anyone who wants to use this code is free to, but this is probably not the most elegant way to do this.
